# Convert field value from 1,000 to numeric

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a field called "sales" and the source data is piping in a value with a comma (ex: 1,000) instead of 1000 (without commas).

How can I convert this value to a numeric (without commas)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the comma:

```
select replace(sales, ',', '')::numeric
```

Comment: @cyahahn . . . So much for having the answer several minutes before anyone else.

Comment: Sorry, I surely didn't see it at that time. It should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select replace(sales, ',', '')::numeric from tablename;
```

`replace(sales, ',', '')` to remove commas (',') and `::numeric` to convert value to numeric.